# Building NodeJs with Cross-Compiling Toolchain - icupkg: /usr/lib/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found

Tags: c++, node.js, ubuntu, cross-compiling, synology

I'm barely new with compiling NodeJs from sources but I really need to do it to build a custom package for the Synology package store.
They've got a chrooted environnement with a dedicated toolchain for every type of device.
Actually I'm using the [braswell with DSM 7.2](https://archive.synology.com/download/ToolChain) .

I've tryed the same build process against these node tags:

- 14.21.3
- 16.20.0
- 18.17.0
- 20.4.0
  The result is the same whatever I try:
  `/source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg: /usr/lib/libm.so.6: version` GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg)`

I'm actually using WSL-2 with Ubuntu 22.04, but I've got the same issue with an Ubuntu 22.04 vanilla.

The build process runs with these commands and properties:

```
PKG_NAME=nodejs
INST_DIR=/tmp/_${PKG_NAME}

LDFLAGS+=$(pkg-config --libs libnl libnl-genl)


env CC="${CC}" CXX="${CXX}" LD="${LD}" AR="${AR}" LINK="${CXX}" STRIP="${STRIP}" RANLIB="${RANLIB}" NM=${NM} \
    CFLAGS="${CFLAGS}" CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS $CFLAGS" \
    LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -ldbus-1" \
    ./configure \
    --dest-cpu=x86_64 --dest-os=linux --cross-compiling \
    --prefix=${INST_DIR}

make ${MAKE_FLAGS}
```

With the Env vars values as following:

```
CC=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-wrap-gcc
CXX=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-wrap-g++
LD=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ld
AR=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar
STRIP=
RANLIB=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ranlib
NM=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-nm
CFLAGS=-DSYNOPLAT_F_X86_64 -O2 -DBUILD_ARCH=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=602 -DSYNO_BRASWELL -DSYNO_PLATFORM=BRASWELL
CXXFLAGS=-DSYNOPLAT_F_X86_64 -O2 -DBUILD_ARCH=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=602 -DSYNO_BRASWELL -DSYNO_PLATFORM=BRASWELL
LDFLAGS=-lnl-3 -lnl-genl-3 -lnl-3 -ldbus-1

MAKE_FLAGS= -j 12
```

And at every run of the build it pass completely the configure without warnings or errors and builds a lot of components, stopping everithing at the "linking" (i suppose) of this one:

```
/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-wrap-g++ -o /source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg -pthread -rdynamic -m64  -Wl,--start-group /source/nodejs/out/Release/obj.host/icupkg/deps/icu-small/source/tools/icupkg/icupkg.o /source/nodejs/out/Release/obj.host/icupkg/tools/icu/no-op.o /source/nodejs/out/Release/obj.host/tools/icu/libicutools.a  -Wl,--end-group 

  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/source/nodejs/out/Release/lib.host:/source/nodejs/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../tools/icu; mkdir -p /source/nodejs/out/Release/obj/gen; "/source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg" -tl ../../deps/icu-tmp/icudt70l.dat "/source/nodejs/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt70l.dat" 

/source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg: /usr/lib/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg) 

/source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg) 

/source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg) 

/source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg) 

/source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /source/nodejs/out/Release/icupkg) 

tools/icu/icudata.target.mk:13: recipe for target '/source/nodejs/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt70l.dat' failed 

make[1]: *** [/source/nodejs/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt70l.dat] Error 1
```

From chrooted environnement:

```
CHROOT@ds.braswell[/]# ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.21
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

```
CHROOT@ds.braswell[/]# /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-wrap-g++ --version
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ (GCC) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
CHROOT@ds.braswell[/]# /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-wrap-gcc --version
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
CHROOT@ds.braswell[/]# /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.38
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

```
CHROOT@ds.braswell[/]# /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-nm --version
GNU nm (GNU Binutils) 2.38
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

```
CHROOT@ds.braswell[/]# ldconfig -p | grep -E "(libc.so|ld-linux-x86-64.so)"
        libc.so.6 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /usr/lib/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (ELF, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /usr/lib32/libc.so.6
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

```
CHROOT@ds.braswell[/]# /usr/lib32/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.21, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.9.2 20150304 (prerelease).
Available extensions:
        crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
        GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
        Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
        BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.archlinux.org/>.
```

```
CHROOT@ds.braswell[/]# /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-root/lib/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.36.
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 12.2.0.
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC ABSOLUTE
Minimum supported kernel: 3.2.0
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>.
```

Does anyone had this issue?
How can I debug deeper to have some additional infos or resolve the GLIBC conflict?

The desiderata is to have the nodejs compiled for that specific architecture with that specific toolchain, but I can change sources both in my package description and in nodejs sources, not in toolchain.

Many thanks in advance for any advice.